# Assign a list to part of a column python

Tags: python, pandas

df1 has shape 4 column with 5 rows, and df2 has shape 2 columns with 7 rows.

I need to assign 1 column consisting of 10 rows into df2 consisting of 7 rows.
, starting at index 1.
df1

```
  First Name      last Name         
1. John          Smith              
2. Mary          Brohowski           
3. Aristidis     Papageorgopoulos   
4. James         Watss               
5. Kid           Red
```

df2

```
 First Name     Last Name   
0. Marty          Smith
1. Sandy          Kevin          
2. Parry          Brohowski      
3. May            Dave      
4. Manny          Garido         
5. Rudy           Red         
6. Wesley         Rednap         
7. Ben            Papageo
```

how can i change rows 1:5 in First Name column in df2, starting with index 0 with df1 Name column, starting with column 1
so the out put will be :

df2

```
   First Name     Last Name   
0. Marty          Smith          
1. John           Kevin          
2. Mary           Brohowski      
3. Aristidis      Dave          
4. James          Garido     
5. Kid            Red
6. Wesley         Rednap         
7. Ben            Papageo
```

ive tried:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()

start_row = 1
i = 1
for i in range(start_row, len(df2)-1):

    while i < len(df2):
        df2[i] = df1[i]
    else:
        break
```

any help pls

Answer (score 2):

Try `merge` to merge to dataframe.

```py
new_df = df1.merge(left_on='Last Name', right_on='Last Name', how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) after selecting the `First Name` column as a dataframe:

```
df1[['First Name']].combine_first(df2)
```

---

```
  First Name  Last Name
0      Marty      Smith
1       John      Kevin
2       Mary  Brohowski
3  Aristidis       Dave
4      James     Garido
5        Kid        Red
6     Wesley     Rednap
7        Ben    Papageo
```

Comment: Great solution @anky_91, i have another situation to reproduce where df1['Person'] is the column instead of 'First Name' and i need to leave it as 'Person'. How would that work?

Comment: @Jienkles do you mean something like: `df1[['First Name']].combine_first(df2).rename(columns={'First Name':'Person'})` ?

Comment: Or same way you can rename df2 first name to person and then do combine first. `df1[['Person']].combine_first(df2.rename(columns={'First Name' :'Person' })) `

Comment: @anky_91 how can i do the same thing but paste into a row from df2? grateful for your help

Comment: @Jienkles i am not clear with the question, but did you try swapping the df1 and df2 in the combine first? If yes, what is your expected result?